# AWS GreenGrass connectivity issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-greengrass

**greengrass v1.8.1 log**

```
[2019-08-02T03:30:28.743-04:00][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp: lookup a1ijl5s1n8kf6a-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:49567->127.0.$

[2019-08-02T03:30:28.743-04:00][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-08-02T03:30:39.74-04:00][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-08-02T03:30:39.74-04:00][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.        {"attemptId": "nVwA", "clientId": "YoungsoftIoTGroup_Core", "errorStrin$
[2019-08-02T03:30:59.742-04:00][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp: lookup a1ijl5s1n8kf6a-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:49845->127.0.$

[2019-08-02T03:30:59.742-04:00][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-08-02T03:31:10.741-04:00][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-08-02T03:31:10.741-04:00][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.       {"attemptId": "BAxL", "clientId": "YoungsoftIoTGroup_Core", "errorStrin$
[2019-08-02T03:31:30.742-04:00][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp: lookup a1ijl5s1n8kf6a-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:39151->127.0.$

[2019-08-02T03:31:30.742-04:00][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-08-02T03:31:41.741-04:00][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-08-02T03:31:41.741-04:00][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.       {"attemptId": "mQbd", "clientId": "YoungsoftIoTGroup_Core", "errorStrin$
[2019-08-02T03:32:03.742-04:00][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp: lookup a1ijl5s1n8kf6a-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:46991->127.0.$

[2019-08-02T03:32:03.742-04:00][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-08-02T03:32:14.741-04:00][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-08-02T03:32:14.741-04:00][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.       {"attemptId": "UDaF", "clientId": "YoungsoftIoTGroup_Core", "errorStrin$
[2019-08-02T03:32:41.743-04:00][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp: lookup a1ijl5s1n8kf6a-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:56790->127.0.$
```

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04. I used AWS IoT greengrass v1.8.1.

I followed the `README.md` in each package to setup up and install step by step. All lambdas were failed to connect AWS greengrass group I created.

This is all was working and all of a sudden encountered this issue.

Comment: Are you able to lookup the AWS IoT DNS entry from your Ubuntu system using `nslookup a1ijl5s1n8kf6a-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: @MartinLöper 

When i tried nslookup below as the output

`;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Comment: Do you have internet connectivity at all on that machine?

Comment: @MartinLöper Yes  i have good internet connectivity by the way thats a cloud box

Comment: @MartinLöper  Latest error trace 

Worker consumed all allocated memory! Memory Usage (KB). {"workerId": "53ffd32f-0e46-488a-6065-01752301c14a", "funcArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:265589871906:function:emi-accelerator-lambda-server-164:2", "memSize": 65536, "memUsed": 86324}